# Use different document roots for subfolder of URL

Tags: apache

I have a PHP application that uses an MVC framework, with Apache on Linux.

Let us say it lives here `http://example.com` on the web and here `/srv/www/example.com` on my server.

I want `http://example.com/blog` to use a WordPress install from here `/srv/www/blog` and all the root web traffic to go to my MVC app (as shown above)

How can this be done?

Comment: `Alias` -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias , but you cannot do this in .htaccess, it has to be server config/virtual host.

Answer (score 3):

In a .htaccess file or your httpd.conf:

```
Alias /blog/ /srv/www/blog/
```

Note the trailing slash.